# Haskell: Error: Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a simple Haskell program that adds an exclamation mark ! to the end of an inputted string by the user. However my program won't run. This is my code:

```
addExFunction :: String -> String
addExFunction x = x ++ "!"

main = do
 putStrLn "enter string: "
 input <- getLine
 addExFunction input
```

This is what my error looks like:

```
a.hs:7:2: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: IO Char
        Actual type: String
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: addExFunction input
      In the expression:
        do putStrLn "enter string: "
           input <- getLine
           addExFunction input
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do putStrLn "enter string: "
                 input <- getLine
                 addExFunction input
  |
7 |  addExFunction input
  |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am new to Haskell. How do I fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: `addExFunction input` does not return an `IO ...`, so you can not add this as last line (since other actions are `IO` in this do-block). You can for example use `print (addExFunction input)`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `return (addExFunction input)` would type check, although an `IO` action that doesn't actually have a side effect wouldn't be very useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`addExFunction input` is a `String`. In the main `do` block, you need to use IO actions instead. What do you want to do with the string? If you want to print it, say so:

```
main = do
   ...
   putStrLn (addExFunction input)
```